# Resize Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to resize a range by looking down the rows of a column for the next used value, however I am getting an object defined error. Any ideas?

```
Set vrng = ActiveSheet.Range("details_table").Find(sest, , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set vrng = vrng.Resize(vrng.End(xlDown).Row)
```

Comment: How do you want to resize this? Say you find `sest` in A10. You want to take that and then the range to the next non-empty cell?

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the .row at the end of your second line if that does not work then try

```
Set vrng = Range(vrng,vrng.end(xldown))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim vrng As Range

Set vrng = Range("Compannies").Find(what:="Delta", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set vrng = vrng.Resize(vrng.Rows.End(xlDown).Row)
vrng.Select
End Sub
```

You just need to make sure you use `vrng.rows` before `.End(xldown)`.

However, I recommend changing the first variable's name, to something like `sestCell`, then using `Set vrng = sestCell.Resize(sestcell.Rows.End(xldown).Row)` to avoid confusion.

What it's doing is, your `Find` is going to return a cell range (specifically, a cell address).  Then, since you want to EXPAND that range down, you need to specify that you want to expand the rows of the range: `.Resize(vrng.rows.End(xldown).Row)`.

Comment: i tried your code in my macro, but for some reason still getting an error half way through cycling all cells

Comment: What error, what does it say? What line is highlighted when you hit "Debug"?  It runs okay on my computer.

Comment: I edited the code - you need to explicitly tell the `Find` to `LookIn and LookAt`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no more data after `vrng` then `.End(xlDown).Row` will return the number of rows in the worksheet. Lets assume `vrng` is A100:

```
Set vrng = Range("A100")
'// There is no data below vrng, so:
nextRow = vrng.End(xlDown).Row '// Returns 65,536 (pretend it's XL97)

vrng.Resize(nextRow) '// <~~ This will error
```

The `Resize()` method *expands* the given range object, so if we're starting at A100 and expanding by 65,536 rows then that would be A65636 which doesn't exist, and so an error occurs.

I would suggest using an Immediate If to manage this:

```
Set vrng = vrng.Resize(IIf(vrng.End(xlDown).Row = Rows.Count, vrng.Rows.Count, vrng.End(xlDown).Row - vrow.Cells(1).Row)
```

If you're not familiar with Immediate If then a regular If block will work:

```
If Not vrng.End(xlDown).Row = Rows.Count Then
    Set vrng = vrng.Resize(vrng.End(xlDown).Row - vrng.Cells(1).Row, )
End If
```